# How can I dynamically make a query based on an HTML item ID?

Tags: php, html, ajax

So, I have this piece of HTML code which is just a navigation bar.

```
<div class="views">
        <b>Views</b>
        <hr style="background-color:#f0efef;">
        <table id="views_table">
          <tr class="item">
            <td class="view" id="my_open_cases">My Open Cases</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="item">
            <td class="view" id="my_pending_cases">My Pending & On Hold Cases</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="item">
            <td class="view" id="my_solved_cases">My Solved Cases</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="item">
            <td class="view" id="my_csat_cases">My CSat Cases</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="item">
            <td class="view" id="my_open_cases">My Open Cases</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="item">
          <td class="view" id="WW Support Tier 1"><a href="escalationreview.php"><div>Escalation Review</div></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="item">
            <td class="view" id="WW Support Tier 1"><a href="wwt1.php"><div>WW Support Tier 1</div></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

And then I have this php file which makes a query in my MySQL database and displays all the information in a table.

```
<?php

        if ( !$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "zendesk_data") ){
            $output="Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;      
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT status, id, subject, requester, requested, requested_updated, service, next_sla_breach FROM escalationreview";
            if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $output="<table class='queue_table'> 
                    <tr align='left'>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Requester</th>
                    <th>Requested</th>
                    <th>Requested Updated</th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Next SLA Breach</th></tr>";
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $output.= "<tr><td>". $row["status"]. "</td><td><a href='../tickets/new.php?tid=" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["id"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["subject"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requester"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requested"]. "</td><td>". $row["requested_updated"]. "</td><td>".
                        $row["service"]. "</td><td>". $row["next_sla_breach"]. "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    $output.="</table>";
                } else { 
                    $output= "0 results"; 
                }
            } else {
                    $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    echo $output;
    }
?>
```

Now, what I want to achieve is: I want to call this php functiom everytime I click on an item in the navigation bar, then send the ID of the item clicked to the php function and query based on that ID, something like this:

**HTML**

```
 <tr class="item">
          <td class="view" id="WW Support Tier 1" onclick="fill(this.id)"><a href="escalationreview.php"><div>Escalation Review</div></a></td>
          </tr>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    function fill($id){
        if ( !$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "zendesk_data") ){
            $output="Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;      
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT status, id, subject, requester, requested, requested_updated, service, next_sla_breach FROM $id";
            if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $output="<table class='queue_table'> 
                    <tr align='left'>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Requester</th>
                    <th>Requested</th>
                    <th>Requested Updated</th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Next SLA Breach</th></tr>";
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $output.= "<tr><td>". $row["status"]. "</td><td><a href='../tickets/new.php?tid=" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["id"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["subject"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requester"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requested"]. "</td><td>". $row["requested_updated"]. "</td><td>".
                        $row["service"]. "</td><td>". $row["next_sla_breach"]. "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    $output.="</table>";
                } else { 
                    $output= "0 results"; 
                }
            } else {
                    $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    echo $output;
    }
?>
```

I know the above code does not work, it is just an idea of how I imagine this could work.

I believe this can be achieved using AJAX but I'm not completely sure. Any guidance here would be highly appreciated! Thanks beforehand.

Comment: There are 1000's of AJAX tutorials out there on the web. Read a few and give it a try, then if you cannot get it working ask a question about the problem

Comment: _PS_ If you have a function called `fill()` you have to call it to make it do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP file renders the whole html, you might not need AJAX at all and just fill the link of each navigation item with the id as query parameter:

```
<td class="view" id="WW Support Tier 1">
    <a href="escalationreview.php?id="<?= urlencode("WW Support Tier 1") ?>"><div>Escalation Review</div></a></td>
</tr>
```

Then in your PHP file, just get the ID as parameter

```
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"] ?? null;
    if($id) {
       fill($id);
    }
    
    function fill($id) {
        if ( !$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "zendesk_data") ){
            $output="Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;      
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT status, id, subject, requester, requested, requested_updated, service, next_sla_breach FROM $id";
            if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $output="<table class='queue_table'> 
                    <tr align='left'>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Requester</th>
                    <th>Requested</th>
                    <th>Requested Updated</th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Next SLA Breach</th></tr>";
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $output.= "<tr><td>". $row["status"]. "</td><td><a href='../tickets/new.php?tid=" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["id"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["subject"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requester"]. "</td><td>" . $row["requested"]. "</td><td>". $row["requested_updated"]. "</td><td>".
                        $row["service"]. "</td><td>". $row["next_sla_breach"]. "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    $output.="</table>";
                } else { 
                    $output= "0 results"; 
                }
            } else {
                    $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
        
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', this.id);
$.ajax({
        url: "./yourPage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        complete: (response) => {
            console.log(response.responseText)
        }
     })
```

### in yourPage.php:

```
function fill($_REQUEST["id"]){ .... your code that you wrote above}
```